# Why does my python script just open IDLE?

Tags: python

I can't understand why running my Python program just opens IDLE.

Not sure if this is more appropriate on SuperUser, but here goes: I can't run python scripts from my command line.

OSX 10.7.4, fresh install of python 3.2.3. I've got the following python script as `test.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
print("hello world")
```

I then make it executable:

```
$> chmod +x test.py
```

Then **all** of the following cause the terminal to open IDLE, with no other output of any kind, i.e. the script is not run:

- python test.py
- python -i test.py
- ./test.py

Even `python -c 'print(5)'` dumps me into IDLE without actually executing the command! IDLE itself works fine. Anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: It's probably fine here, StackOverflow covers dev tools which python definitely is.

Comment: What happens when you just type `python` at the command line? How about `which python`?

Comment: Just `python` opens IDLE, which I believe is the correct behavior. `which python` gives me `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python`

Comment: On every system I've ever worked with, `python` opens a command-line REPL, not IDLE. Is your goal to get it to run the script in the command line, or in IDLE?

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant command-line REPL, not IDLE. My goal is running the script in the command line. See accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very sure about the problem, but have you tried to run

```
python3 test.py
```

or change the shebang line to python3?

trying to take a look at the content in your "python" console script (e.g. by `file which python`) may also help reveal why it is linked to IDLE.

Comment: `python3 test.py` works, so does changing the shebang, as suggested. Thanks!